# Сгенерировать N псевдослучайных чисел из диапазона [a;b)

Tags: c++, python, numpy

Есть ли в питоне/numpy аналог функции `std::generate` из `C++`? У меня есть функция без параметров, которая возвращает единственное значение. Надо создать numpy массив/список из n элементов, n раз вызвав эту функцию.

Определение функции:

```
def generator():
    return (b - a) * np.random.random_sample(N) + a
```

Comment: а чем вам не угодил: `arr = np.array([func() for _ in range(n)])`?

Comment: @MaxU я так и написал пока, но хотелось бы более читабельно + более эффективно (сразу создать np.array, а не из листа)

Comment: Если хотите эффективно, то лучше переписать вашу функцию таким образом, чтобы она возвращала вектор из `n` значений. Использование циклов в Numpy / Pandas - зло, которого нужно стараться избегать...

Comment: можете привести в вопросе определение функции?

Comment: @MaxU привёл, это просто случайная генерация вектора с заданными границами

Comment: а что такое `a` и `b`?

Comment: @MaxU границы элементов вектора. Чтобы лежало не в [0;1), а в [a;b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [np.random.uniform()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html):

```
In [99]: a, b, n = -2, 5, 10

In [100]: arr = np.random.uniform(a, b, size=n)

In [101]: arr
Out[101]: array([ 2.51026004,  3.77415304, -1.16321601,  3.37084398,  4.68975964,  2.83651918,  3.78757424,  1.83671277,  2.25705065,  3.38001105])
```